# Loading OpenTok libraries on Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, composer-php, opentok

I have been trying to load [OpenTok PHP SDK](https://github.com/opentok/opentok-php-sdk) in Codeigniter. There is no actual any repository of Codeigniter with OpenTok. 
I tried to add OpenTok folder directly into libraries folder and called `$this->load->library('OpenTok');` But it didn't help.

Currently, I was using like this in core PHP.

```
require "vendor/autoload.php";
use OpenTok\OpenTok;
use OpenTok\MediaMode;
use OpenTok\ArchiveMode;
use OpenTok\Session;
use OpenTok\Role;
```

The library we get from OpenTok is composer package. My Question is how to call those in Codeigniter. Any OpenTok developer here who had used OpenTok in Codeigniter?

Appreciate your help.Thanks

Comment: You can try using it as a package by putting those files in third_party folder? https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/loader.html

Comment: @TigerTiger I have used as you suggested and it's working. But can you check my comment on Brian's answer? Need your opinion. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In config/config.php:

```
$config['composer_autoload'] = TRUE;
```

Your composer.json file needs to be inside the application directory. It's probably going to look something like this:

```
{
    "name": "nsqdev/project",
    "description": "NSQ DEV PROJECT",
    "type": "application",
    "license": "Proprietary",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "NSQ DEV",
            "email": "nsqdev@nsqdev.com"
        }
    ],
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "require": {
        "opentok/opentok": "3.0.*"
    }
}
```

Use composer commands from that location (/application), like "composer install".

Now, in your controller, model, or wherever you want to run opentok:

```
use OpenTok\OpenTok;
$opentok = new OpenTok($apiKey, $apiSecret);
```

Hope this helps. The composer.json file may not be perfect, as you may want or need to change the version of opentok. Otherwise, composer usage in CodeIgniter is pretty easy, and gives you access to lots of packages.

More info:

As @tpojka states, you could use require from the command line. Details for usage available in the composer documentation: https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#require

For general basic usage of composer, start here: https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md

Comment: No need for JSON file. Just use of `composer require opentok/opentok` after composer_autoload is enabled.

Comment: @Brian Gottier I have copied **vendor folder** to **third_party folder** and and loading autoload.php before the class like this: 
`require_once APPPATH . 'third_party/vendor/autoload.php';  
use OpenTok\OpenTok;
$opentok = new OpenTok($apiKey, $apiSecret); `  and to use in function I am using global $opentok; 

Is this wise practice? I don't think it is

Comment: No, don't do that. Let CodeIgniter handle the composer autoload, and put your packages where they were designed to be put. I know you know what's going on now, but imagine when you come back to this project in 1, 2, or 5 years and have to work on it. You'll be much happier if you do it the right way.

Comment: Yes! you are absolutely right.It's been just a few weeks on CodeIgniter. Do you have any suggestions on this learning phase? Like, use some required library or structure follow anything. Thanks again for help @Brian

Comment: I just recommend reading the user guide, and then read it again. Do it for fun. Do it until you are bored because you know everything.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can’t load the OpenTok file as a library in CodeIgniter because the loader class was originally built when namespaces didn’t exist. CodeIgniter has added namespace support in v4 phase 1:

https://bcit-ci.github.io/CodeIgniter4/general/modules.html#namespaces

I recommend using the OpenTok PHP SDK as @brian-gottier mentioned!   You can also find more information setting up OpenTok in PHP here: https://github.com/opentok/OpenTok-PHP-SDK

They have a couple of sample applications that can help you get started!